# Is there a way to reduce the size of a preprocessed source of a compiler bug test case using Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor, testcase

I ran into an issue with the Intel compiler and wondered if there was a way to automatically reduce the size of the preprocessed source. It seems a lot of standard headers (of which quite some unnecessary code) were pulled in, and I'd like to reduce it to a minimum to help the engineers fix the problem.

Comment: There are some tools on [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/A_guide_to_testcase_reduction).

Comment: What  you need is a tool that determines the dependencies of one definition on another, that elminates definitions not used by main.    These tools mostly don't exist; we built one custom for parsing C files because it cut the final parse tree size by ~~ 95%.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-processor doesn't know what code is important and what's not.  It is often possible to have all of the standard library includes listed first which means that you can focus on just the end of the pre-processed file in order to debug your own code.  This method has worked well for me for debugging complex macros.